# valgrind profile error after lib replace

Tags: c++, eclipse, valgrind, eclipse-cdt

I used to profile a c++ app developed with eclipse CDT using valgrind (memcheck+helgrind). The application uses a static lib (libpodofo.a). After I modified and rebuild the library(podofo) the application runs fine, but valgrind says

> Launching myapp(1)" has encountered a problem. Error starting process (Cannot parse PID from output file).

I have no idea where to start. Any idea?

The error apparently occurs when it tries to make calls from the library (judging by console output).

I don't know what code I could post since app runs without error.

Library is podofo.

Comment: @osgx Thank you for the edit. Sorry for the formatting.

Comment: It's ok. Can you give more information, how valgrind is started and what it says? Or even try to launch valgrind from console.

Comment: These are the params called from eclipse. 
They are the same when running with both version of the .a files. valgrind --tool=helgrind -q 
--log-file=.....txt 
--trace-children=yes 
--child-silent-after-fork=yes 
--run-libc-freeres=yes --demangle=yes --num-callers=12 --error-limit=yes --show-below-main=yes --max-stackframe=2000000 --main-stacksize=0 --track-lockorders=yes --hystory-level=full --conflict-cache-size=1000000 myapp appparams

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
It was the code(obviously) it was a variable that hadn't been initialized, valgrind was actually killed by a null pointer.